# 出てこないと気持ちは落ち着かない meaning

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

> 「ハリー・ポッター」シリーズには、ロンやハーマイオニーだけでなく「ネビル・ロングボトム」が出てこないと気持ちは落ち着かない。

My western brain can't comprehend the final part of the sentence! I know でてくる is something like "show up" and 落ち着く something like "calm down, harmonize".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

気持ちは落ち着かない = not to feel at ease.

Thus

「ハリー・ポッター」シリーズには、ロンやハーマイオニーだけでなく「ネビル・ロングボトム」が出てこないと気持ちは落ち着かない

can be translated into something like

"I would not feel at ease if Neville Longbottom didn't show up, even if Ron and Hermione do (did?) in the Harry Potter series."